# Install C++ extension for Python

Tags: python, c++, installation, hash, package

I'm quite a noob in Python, but I'm using PyCharm as my IDE and I want to install and use TLSH: https://pypi.org/project/python-tlsh/

So what I did (in order to use TLSH, I have to install python-tlsh, so I run this command in the windows command prompt (run as an administrator):

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts>pip install python-tlsh
```

but then I get this error:

```
`Collecting python-tlsh
  Using cached python-tlsh-4.5.0.tar.gz (40 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: python-tlsh
  Building wheel for python-tlsh (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'tlsh' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-tlsh
  Running setup.py clean for python-tlsh
Failed to build python-tlsh
Installing collected packages: python-tlsh
  Running setup.py install for python-tlsh ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for python-tlsh did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'tlsh' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> python-tlsh

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.`
```

so I installed Microsoft Visual C++ x64 (at least I think I did): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170,  I continued without code (maybe I need an account or so..?), but it still doesn't work. I tried it via the terminal of PyCharm, doesn't work either.

@tyfon-e Thank you, but then I get a similar error, also when I execute it in the terminal of Pycharm. it keeps saying that I need Visual Studio, while I already installed Build Tools and Community and also enabled C++ Build Tools

Also, Stackoverflow rejects my edit because "I should have posted it as a comment", not considering the fact that I can't post comments because it's a relatively new account and I need to have 50 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install it from Pycharm Settings.
Head to File --> Settings --> Project then Python Interpreter.
down you will have "+" button, click it and search for it there.
[`Look at this Image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeiRT.png)

Comment: Please share actual instructions